# Universal Robots - joint speed control

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, ros-kinetic, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings.

I am quite new with ROS and I am still pending to identify something.

Is there already implemented in ROS the control of joint speeds for Universal Robots manipulators?

I have identified the *speedJ()* function from URScript language (native for UR controllers), which allow joint speed control, but not for ROS.

Any information will be welcome.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321576/universal-robots---joint-speed-control/) by [wagnerbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/40981/wagnerbra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least the [ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver) supports joint velocity control with the `ros_control` setup in `kinetic-devel` (the old driver (`master` branch, deprecated) supported a `/joint_speed` topic, but that has not been ported to the new version).

Velocity setpoints are directly mapped onto `speedj(..)` statements on the controller.

See [ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver#218](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/issues/218) for some discussion on using `ros_control`'s `JointGroupVelocityController`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2